# CakePHP and Opauth

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I started implementing [Opauth for CakePHP](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth). It's awesome that it's easy to login via Facebook, Twitter...

Question is once Opauth returns login data what would be an efficient way to login the user to CakePHP?

Opauth doesn't login the user to CakePHP. I think I'm supposed to create a user and save the facebook or other auth info to the db. Is there a plugin that allows me to do this easily?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you do. Go forth! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing I love about CakePHP 2.0 was the way the Auth Plugins work, you can really customize one ore more Authentication methods. At the same time this leaves it to the developer to 'hook in' custom Auth Plugins to integrate the solution.

The plugin page has your answer, almost

- Goto https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth#how-to-use
- check step `#6` "*After validation, user will be redirected to `Router::url('/opauth-complete')` with validated auth response data retrievable available at `$this->data`*"
- after this is complete and you have code like their example `public function opauth_complete() {...`
- in this function you will use the `$this->data` to find your User that was authenticated
- a method I use at times is to find the user by 2 pieces of information that is provided by Opauth *example: username and email*
- you can use something like `$loginUser = $this->User->find('first', array('fields'=>array('User.*'), 'conditions'=>array('User.username'=>$this->data['username'], 'User.email'=>$this->data['email']));`
- once you have the user in `$loginUser` you can just call the `$this->Auth->login($loginUser)` and you will now have an AuthSession with that user!

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar what you mentioned. The main difference is that I saved the opauth result to a `user_oauths` table. This way I can handle connecting Twitter to accounts (cause twitter doesn't give out emails). I also save the token/secret so that I can use it to share stuff without generating it again until it expires.